# Xml content length issue in the post method handler of ratpack

Tags: handler, ratpack

In post method handler of ratpack the following is not executed after certain length of xml. Tried changing the content length but it did not work.Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
  ctx.request.getBody().then{ body->
                println body.text
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default max content length is 1mb. You can change the [maxContentLength](https://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/server/ServerConfigBuilder.html#maxContentLength-int-) though:

```
serverConfig {
    maxContentLength(someVal)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But in my case the size was lesser than 1MB. The issue was I had a render startement at the end of the function so it was rendering before the execution of the above code after certain content length.Its working perfectly after removing the render statement at the end.

Comment: Ah ok, I mistook you when you said you set the content length as setting the header. Glad you got it sorted out.